# Dynamic assignment of values as default parameters in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Whenever I run this pipeline in Jenkins I have to manually copy-paste some values from a YAML file in a remote Gitlab repository. What I would like to achieve is an auto-fill of the values that .
This is how my Jenkinsfile and the YAML look like:

Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
   agent {
       docker {
           image 'artifactory...'
           args "..."
       }
   }

   parameters {
       string(name: 'BACKEND_TAG_1', defaultValue: '', description: 'Tag...')
       string(name: 'BACKEND_TAG_2', defaultValue: '', description: 'Tag...')
   }

stage('prepare') {
           steps {
               script {                  
                   dir('application') {
                       git url: env.PIPELINE_APPLICATION_GIT_URL, branch: env.PIPELINE_APPLICATION_GIT_BRANCH
                   }
                   Values = readYaml file: 'application/values.yaml'
```

values.yaml

```
version:
  default: 0.1.2
  company_tag_1: 0.1.124
  company_tag_2: 0.1.230
```

So I need to loop into the parameters and assign the corresponding values:

```
Values.each { Value ->
  Value.version.minus('company')

/* This value should be assigned to the corresponding parameter BACKEND_TAG_* parameter.
e.g.: BACKEND_TAG_1.default=company_tag_1
      BACKEND_TAG_2.default=company_tag_2
*/
}
```

Reading the YAML works fine but I don't know how to proceed in the assignment of the values.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you would like to populate all parameters before click Build button. I mean after clicking "Build with Parameters" button, you basically would like to see your parameters are populated from your YAML file.

If this is the case You can use Active Choice Parameter or Extended Choice Parameter plugins for this purpose. These Plugins are able to run Groovy Script, so you can develop a small Groovy Script read and select parameters automatically.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to have the pipeline getting the changes without running it without parameters?

Comment: @parax If I understood you correctly, If you use those plugins you don't have to build the job. It will automatically populate whenever you click to Build job button. You can see some examples in here: https://medium.com/@rijoalvi/jenkins-dynamic-parameters-using-extended-choice-parameter-plugin-and-groovy-1a6ffc41063f